# setar posição da barra de rolagem em um iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Tenho uma página com um #iframe, e quando a página carregar, preciso que o scroll do iframe deslize horizontalmente até o fim (para a direita).

Tentei diversas maneiras mas até agora nada.

```
jQuery("#iframe").contents().find("html,body").animate({scrollLeft:100}, 1000);
```

Alguem saberia me ajudar ?

Comment: É um iframe de uma url interna ou externa?

Comment: uma url interna ! (action="../teste/index.php")

Answer (score 0):

Você quase conseguiu.

Teste apenas adicionar o seu código no `$(window).load()` e veja o que acontece.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    jQuery("#iframe").contents().find("html,body").animate({scrollLeft:100}, 1000);
});
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional](http://jsfiddle.net/6thKV/3/)

Vale lembrar que pode existir alguns bloqueios de seguranças no iframe, impedindo assim o funcionamento.

Para mais informações, veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24763802/4843158), que acho que irá lhe ajudar bastante.

Comment: ótima dica ! Mas não consegui fazer funcionar ainda !

Comment: não consigo acesssar o iframe pela função scrollLeft(), não consigo pegar a posição do scroll, segue o link
http://westlucaya.com/index.php/br/status-e-mapa-do-local